# Angular binding method or variable

Tags: angular

Let say I have this component with the following template

```
<div *ngFor="let t of test">{{t}}</div>
```

And this code

```
  test: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.test = this.test.reduce((a, b) => {
      a.push(b * 10);
      return a;
    }, []);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.test.push(4);
    }, 3000);
  }
```

This will be result in this

```
10
20
30
4 // not what I was looking for
```

However if I decide to move the code in a method `getTest()`

```
<div *ngFor="let t of getTest()">{{t}}</div>
```

with the code

```
  getTest(): number[] {
    return this.test.reduce((a, b) => {
      a.push(b * 10);
      return a;
    }, []);
  }
```

Then the delayed value will show as `40` which is what I was looking for.

Is this a valid implementation or is resource consuming? `getTest()` method seems to be called quite often.

In a bigger picture I'm trying to add / remove / update items in an array and show a reduced version of that array on screen.

Comment: Of course it will be called quite often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind to a method, it will be called every time Angular runs change detection. This can become a serious performance burden.

It's better to assign the result of the method to a field and bind to the field instead. Change detection with fields is extremely efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Observable using async pipe
like (change rxjs part to your logic)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { reduce, concatMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

test: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
$test:Observable<number>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.$test = from(this.test)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(x => of(40)),
        delay(1000),
        reduce((acc, current) => {
          return  acc + current
        },0)
      );
}
```

in the view

```
{{$test | async}}
```